# How to deal with configuration in new format (appsettings.json) in a console app

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio

Simply stupid question - but I've already spent an hours trying to find out how to read

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
  "param": "value",
  } 
}
```

this simple appsettings.json file from the console application in the proper way?
I've done till this moment

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
Configuration = builder.Build();
var section = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
```

and now I get stuck

Comment: Try this library http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Configuration["AppSettings:param"]`

Comment: Thank you! Exactly last step